# The rectification of the transpose of a skew tableau?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux

Suppose the rectification of a skew tableau is a standard tableau, I want to know if the rectification of the transpose of the skew tableau equals to the transpose of the rectification of the skew tableau? If it's right, how to prove it?

Comment: It is quite clear from the description on wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_taquin that sliding one empty square one step commutes with transposition: one slides in the direction of the smallest square to the right or below.

Comment: @ Per Alexandersson Get it.  Thank you.